# Edit length of increment_id in sales_order table on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to decrease length of order increment #00000000001 to #00001.
I found some tutorials for magento 1 but not for Magento 2.
Please help if someone is aware how to perform this task.

Thanks

Comment: checkout the table "eav_entity_type". I am not sure but its seems this table is responsible for that.

Comment: ya, I have decreased the increment_ped_length value but still don't reflect any change.

Answer (score 6):

In the `etc` directory of your module, add a `di.xml` file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[%s%'.05d%s]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This way Magento will pass a 5 digit pattern instead of its default pattern made by 9 digits.

This is because the first and the last `%s` symbol are replaced respectively with the `prefix` and the `suffix` values stored in the `sales_sequence_profile` table. The matching is done with the `meta_id` of your store (you can check yours by reading from the `sales_sequence_meta` table). The `%'.05d` pattern means that you want an integer with 5 padding digits on its left which is replaced with the next order number calculated by Magento.

For example, assuming that you have:

- Prefix: PX
- Suffix: SX

with the above pattern, the first order number will be `PX00001SX`

Comment: file location - app/etc/di.xml   Cay you explain your code <![CDATA[%s%'.05d%s]]> so other patterns can be created from your answer?

Comment: The cleanest approach to this problem. I was not convinced with the other solutions to override the actual PHP file. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

you can decrease length of order increment #00000000001 to #00001. 
Try this: https://store.emizentech.com/magento2/custom-order-and-invoice-number-magento-2-0.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a custom developed plugin:

I already had an observer to save the customer as new customer automatically after placing an order and before rendering the success page:

On the events.xml (already existing observer i've previously made)

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="customcheckout_customer" instance="Dufry\CustomCheckout\Model\Observer\SaveCustomer"/>
</event>
```

On the observer SaveCustomer.php (already existing observer i've previously made):

```
    $order = $observer->getOrder();

    $increment = $order->getIncrementId();
    if(strlen($increment) > 9){
        $newIncrement = substr($increment, -8);
        $newIncrement = substr($increment,0,1).$newIncrement;
        $order->setIncrementId($newIncrement);
    }

    ...

    $order->save()
```

And worked like a charm.

I did the second "substr" part to keep the prefix the was previously configured.